# WiX ToolSet v3.11 - Error: LGHT0103: They system cannot find the file "..."

Tags: c#, path, environment-variables, wix, wix3.11

I am getting this error when trying to build from VS2019 with Setup configuration.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe" -ext WixUIExtension "...\Product.wixobj" -out "C:...\test.msi"
```

My path is not longer than 255 characters. I am using environment variable:

```
<?define BUILD_OUTPUT_FOLDER=$(env.TEST_RELEASE_FOLDER) ?>
```

Also, for some reason it ignores the last backslash, e.g. `"C:\......\DirectorySubDirFile"`, it should be `"C:\......\Directory\SubDirFile"`

Comment: Did you literally write "..." in the paths or should this only be an abbreviation of something you don't want to show? Wheer ajd how do you use `BUILD_OUTPUT_FOLDER`?  What is this `DirectorySubDirFile`? So many questions.

Comment: No I didn't, it is just abbreviation.

<?define BUILD_OUTPUT_FOLDER=$(env.RADIOSPHERE_RELEASE_FOLDER) ?>

DirectorySubDirFile is an .dll file.